# can we use scanner input for inserting values into database in jdbc program

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a code like this,

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Connectivity {

    public static void main(String[] ar){
        /*Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String a=s.nextLine();
        String b=s.nextLine();
        // Connectivity c=new Connectivity(a,b);*/

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("connecting to databse");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example","pic","picadmin");       
            Statement st=con.createStatement();

            String sql="insert into tbl1(id,catagory) values('102','medicines')";

            st.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Successfully Inserted");
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from tbl1");
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  " + rs.getString(2));
            }
            con.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
        }
    }
}
```

I know it is possible through `PreparedStatement`. But can anyone help me is this possible with scanner object

Comment: Absolutely, read the values in from the `Scanner`, these then become the values you would pass to the `PreapredStatement#setXxx` methods...

Comment: What do you mean is it possible? You can certainly create a parametrised query with values taken from scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It should look something like

```
String sql = "insert into tbl1(id,catagory) values(?, ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, a);
ps.setString(2, b);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

If you must use `Statement` you should probably use something like [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql%28java.lang.String%29) because otherwise you might be vulnerable to SQL Injection,

```
String sql="insert into tbl1(id,catagory) values('" + a + "','" + b + "')";
st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: I got answer with the help of http://www.journaldev.com/2489/jdbc-statement-vs-preparedstatement-sql-injection-example . thanks Elliott Frisch..

Comment: @Saravanamanikandan See also xkcd and [little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse it is possible. First of all as you mentiond you need to use prepared statements to avoid any SQL Injections.

Secondly you will need to do something like the following:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please Enter Category name:");
String catName = s.nextLine();

Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
try{
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example","pic","picadmin"); 
    String sql="insert into tbl1(id,catagory) values('102', ?)";
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, catName);
    stmt.execute()
} catch (SQLException se){
    System.out.println(se.getMessage());
} finally {
    conn.close();
}
```